# Is there a URI that represents the current location in the abstract sense?

Tags: c#, uri, relative-path

I'm curious whether there's a URI that represents the *concept* of the current location.

I tried this code in C#

```
[Test]
public void TestUri()
{
    Uri a = new Uri(".", UriKind.Relative);
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

and it throws `System.UriFormatException : Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

So I have two questions:

1. Is this construct defined as part of the URI specification?
2. If so, how can I construct a conforming instance in C#?

(I realize I could just check the URI reference for null to implement this...)